# Software to allow people to access my computer and vice versa

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the best Remote Desktop Application?](https://superuser.com/questions/1585/whats-the-best-remote-desktop-application)

What software/ web service can I use (both free and commercial) to allow people to remote desktop into my computer from anywhere as long as there is internet?

Same thing, but reverse: what software/web service can I use to access other people's computer?

It should work through all the firewall, easy to use, simple to setup, intuitive, etc.

I think for the first case, would be easiest if the software creates a link (sent via email) and the person just clicks, enters some access code, and *tada* he's connected.

Same with the other case.

Comment: Many similar questions, just click on your remote desktop tag if you're interested. You also haven't specified an operating system.

Answer (score 2):

Fog Creek Copilot does exactly this. [Link here](https://www.copilot.com/)

Comment: I believe that that is free only on the weekends.

Answer (score 0):

The latest [Skype](http://www.skype.com) allows you to do that.

You can use [VNC](http://realvnc.com) to login to a remote machine.  It has a Java mode that allows you to connect with a browser.

I believe the latest [MSN Messenger](http://www.msn.com) allows you to.

Finally, Windows comes with a built-in [remote desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsXp/using/mobility/getstarted/Remoteintro.mspx) tool.

Comment: do i have to install any skype addons to do remote desktop?

Answer (score 0):

I think a recent question on these lines was answered with VNC as the solutions.
You could also look up [Opera-Unite](http://unite.opera.com/) for simple needs.

Answer (score 0):

Citrix makes [GoToMyPC](http://gotomypc.com) which sounds like exactly what you are looking for.  Their software is very easy to set up and use, but it is commercial.  If you're willing to spend some time setting things up, VNC is a free alternative.